# Is it Azure AD B2C or the external IDP that has to set the same site cookie for chrome 80

Tags: google-chrome, azure-ad-b2c, samesite, idp

We have

a react app 
a Azure AD B2C policy 
a external custom IDP

All was working well until chrome 80 and suddenly the app is failing to log in

After googling we cannot identify if its the external idp that needs to set the same site cookie or the Azure AD B2C

Uploaded what cookies - Which ones should b2c set as SameSite ? 
[image]

Can anyone confirm that the Same Site cookie is set in Azure AD B2C

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can take a Fiddler trace to see that same site cookie settings are set correctly in Azure AD B2C already.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer,  so is it possible that B2C is not setting this cookie ? 
Is there a way to enable it

Comment: No, it is not configurable, B2C **will** be setting them correctly, you can see this if you take a Fiddler trace. You may see in the trace that other cookies are not set properly You can also disable same-site in the browser to see if that really is the cause.

Comment: B2C doesnt look like its configuring them and we followed this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/miscellaneous/chrome-behavior-affects-applications

This is the cookies I have before my site kicks me out  (please see top post ) - do i need to ask Azure to update my B2C directory ?

Comment: Those are not B2C cookies, those look to be 'session storage' objects at your applications domain.

Comment: How do i find the B2C cookies in Dev Tools ?
Thanks

Comment: They will not show since the page redirects to your app after the auth succeeds. This is why i said use Fiddler.

Comment: Hey , it all fixed itself, so it does look like my B2C instance just needed to be updated, thanks for the help